# Is there a way to call a method on an auto property set?

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, properties

I am implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on some viewmodels in a WPF project. For this I need to always declare `INotifyPropertyChanged` specific code like in the following example:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _property;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Property");
        }
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The only code that is specific to `ViewModel` is the `Property` while the rest seems to me to be only noise. I have tried to reduce it, considering that I don't have only one viewmodel and that in future there will be more added, by adding an abstract class between the viewmodels and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface this way:

```
public abstract class NotifiableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now all the viewmodels got much shorter, for example:

```
class ViewModel : NotifiableObject
{
    private bool _property;

    public bool Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            _property = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Property));
        }
    }
}
```

Now for every property that I will add, I will not be able to use auto-property, but instead I will have to keep a backed field and always on the setter I will have to call `NotifyPropertyChanged` method. I am looking for a way to avoid this and reduce my code even further to something like:

```
class ViewModel : NotifiableObject
{
    [NotifiableProperty]
    public bool Property { get; set; }
}
```

I am not looking especially for an attribute since [it has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829619/execute-function-kept-in-the-attribute-upon-property-change) related to WPF or [related to C# in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074942/call-method-execute-piece-of-code-using-property-attribute), but for any way to work around this issue.

I know that the code is shorter now, but in future this will have a great impact over the readability of the application. Any improvement suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way to do this, the best way is to have a ViewModelBase class which contains all the common methods like Notify and then inherit the same for all the view models. You will need to have a backed field for the properties that are Two-Way and need to be notified. Also, auto properties internally do the same thing and are useless if you want to provide a default value, hence the current implementation is good enough, you might complicate it more if you try to reduce the code.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar *auto properties [...] are useless if you want to provide a default value*, you mean like `public int MyProp { get; set; } = 10;` which is valid syntax?

Comment: private int _myProp = 10;
public int MyProp { get { return _myProp; } set { _myProp = value; Notify(); } }